# Is onCreateView() the constructor of Fragment class?

Tags: android

I am creating a fragment and adding it to a layout using java code. To do this, i created 2 classes and 2 layouts. One of the classes extends Fragment and other extends FragmentActivity. One of the xml files is the container and other is the fragment. Here is my code:

```
public class FragmentClass extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,false);       
    return v;
}
}
```

And here is how i add the fragment to the layout:

```
public class Fragment_Activity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.container_layout);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.container_layout_eklenecek_yer);

    if(fragment==null){
        fragment=new FragmentClass();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container_layout_eklenecek_yer, fragment).commit();
    }
}
}
```

This code works as i expect, but here is my question: I have a piece of code in Fragment_Activity class that says:

```
fragment=new FragmentClass();
```

and FragmentClass has no constructors. Is a default, empty constructor is called here, or onCreateView works as a constructor? I am confused here.

Thanks

Comment: I'm sure what what the constructor is in that case but if you need one use this

    `public FragmentClass() {
        //Your code here
    }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

You need a default constructor with fragments, a constructor that takes no arguments is a "default constructor" (this might be c++ terminology) because it allows you to construct an object, for certain.

Because Android might need RAM or something it can kill your fragments, it might also bring them back.

If **you** pass stuff to the constructor how will the Android OS know that stuff to pass it to you when it needs to re-create the fragment? It doesn't - this question has no answer.

Hence the default constructor.

When re-creating your fragment Android will attach an activity, and you can use onActivityAttached (or something to that tune, look up fragment life-cycles) to get the activity. If you know the activity implements/extends a `whatever` you can cast that activity to a `whatever` and store it, whatever you need to do.

The onCreateview method is what the name says: the thing that is called that returns a view. It is called when Android wants the view that represents your fragment, it is NOT a constructor, neither to be thought of, or in actual fact.